# How can I setup a network connection for a Docker container running Universal Robots simulator?

Tags: docker, networking, containers, virtualization

I'm using Docker to create a container that is running a Universal Robots simulator with the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/universalrobots/ursim_e-series) using the following command:

`docker run --rm -it -p 5900:5900 -p 6080:6080 universalrobots/ursim_e-series`

In the simulator's settings menu it shows that it isn't connected to a network. I think the container isn't receiving a network connection. When I change the command to...

`docker run --rm -it -net host universalrobots/ursim_e-series`

I'm unable to access the web interface for PolyScope through the prompted url:

`http://192.168.65.4:6080/vnc.html?host=192.168.65.4&port=6080`

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental to docker containers but can't seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

solution: https://forum.universal-robots.com/t/cant-view-docker-ursim-ui/26751

use:

- docker run --rm -it -p 5900:5900 -p 6080:6080 universalrobots/ursim_e-series
- http://localhost:6080/vnc_auto.html